# Unable to locate element for LABEL with the XPath expression

Tags: xpath, label, selenium-webdriver, element, locate

I am trying the below xpath for Label, but I'm not able to locate the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[label[contains(text(),'Patient's Name']]")).isEnabled();
```

XPath: `.//*[@id='update_patient_profile']/div/div[1]/label`  ---Taken from FirePath.

Below is the HTML source for the field.

```
<form id="update_patient_profile" action="/subscriber/" method="post" name="update_patient_profile"> 
  <div class="subscriberAddPatient"> 
    <div class="formData nameInputs"> 
  <label for="first_name">Patient's Name</label>
  <input id="first_name" class="left nameRule" type="text" onblur="resetTxtAdd($(this))" onfocus="emptyFieldAdd($(this))" onclick="emptyFieldAdd($(this))" name="first_name" value="First Name" maxlength="24"/>
```

Can anyone suggest me the correct XPath for the Label.

Comment: Your HTML source is broken, please check that. Have a look at the [FAQ] regarding formatting your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the below **XPATH**

```
 //*[@id='update_patient_profile']//div[2]/label[.='Patient's Name']
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use
**text()** instead of dot **"."**. To verify the label text one can use this path too

```
//form[@id='update_patient_profile']//div[2]/label[text()='Patient's Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

`//form[@id='update_patient_profile']/label[text()='Patient's Name']`

As the `label` tag is also a child of form tag.