# Cannot find element by xpath with webdriver for a label on Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, spyder

I am trying to use a label to identify the next page button on the web search page, I currently have the code

```py
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//label[contains(text(),'Page'+str(page_no+1))]//ancestor:div//input)
```

I got to this stage through this link here:
[Unable to locate element for LABEL with the XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988157/unable-to-locate-element-for-label-with-the-xpath-expression)

I am working in Spyder and it says that this is invalid syntax and won't run the code. I'm not sure why as it seems correct according to the previous answer I followed.

Can someone point out what is wrong with this to me please or identify an alternative code I can use to find element by a label?

Comment: I just want to add page_no is defined in a for loop as I want to go through a range of 10 pages.

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to SO! Can you please post the error message you get?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! I'm working on Spyder and am unable to run the script as it says 'invalid syntax' - this is addressed to the line in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by finding a clickable point for the 'Next page' button, which appeared as a title. I then used this in the code as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next page"]').click()
```